# In PL/SQL i got the following error in triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm getting the following errors

```
Errors for TRIGGER TRIG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/37    PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

**Actual Question is:**

Consider the following relation schemas

```
Emp1
empid   name    salary  dno
   Del_History
dno Rows_deleted    Date1
```

Write a PL/SQL block to delete records of all employees who belong to a particular department and then record the dno, no of rows deleted and date on which deletion occurred in the Del_History table.

```
    create or replace trigger trig after delete on emp1 for each row 

        declare

        d number:=&d;  

        begin

    if deleting then

    update Del_History set dno=d;

    update Del_History set date1=sysdate;

    update Del_History set Rows_deleted=%rowcount;

    end if;

    delete from emp1 where dno=d;

        end;
```

Comment: Format your code and repost your trigger definition

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answering your question directly but some issues with the trigger as posted are:

Your trigger will execute after delete on the table for each row. There is no need to include a delete statement in your trigger. The delete has already happened.

To access column values of the deleted row use  :old.column.

Since this is a row level trigger the value of sql%rowcount will always be 1.

`If deleting` is not necessary since the trigger is only an after delete trigger.

```
create or replace trigger trig
   after delete on emp1
   for each row
declare
begin

      update del_history
         set dno = :old.dno;
      update del_history
         set date1 = sysdate;
      update del_history
         set rows_deleted = sql%rowcount;  -- always 1

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for a trigger as the actual question is *"Write a PL/SQL block"*. Below you'll find an anonymous PL/SQL [block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS141):

> A PL/SQL block is defined by the keywords DECLARE, BEGIN, EXCEPTION, and END. These keywords divide the block into a declarative part, an executable part, and an exception-handling part. Only the executable part is required.

that fullfills all the requirements.

```
-- Write a PL/SQL block ...
declare
  v_department_number constant number := 42;
  v_rows_deleted number;
begin
  -- ... to delete records of all employees who belong to
  -- a particular department ...
  delete from emp1 where dno = v_department_number;

  -- record number of deleted rows
  v_rows_deleted := sql%rowcount;

  -- ... and then record the dno, no of rows deleted and date on
  -- which deletion occurred in the Del_History table.
  insert into del_history (
   dno
  ,rows_deleted
  ,date1
  ) values (
   v_department_number
  ,v_rows_deleted
  ,sysdate
  );
end;
/
```

Comment: sql%rowcount is not working,its showing Error:  insert into Del_History values(d,sql%rowcount,sysdate);
                                    *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 37:
PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @Jash should be fixed now.

Comment: I'm getting the following error                      
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TRIG1' is invalid and failed re-validation
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: @Jash Please study the difference of a trigger and a PL/SQL block.